# Если кликнуть второй раз по открытой вкладке, приложение закрывается

Tags: android-fragment, android, rss

Приложение, rss news, имеет список с темами новостей. Если кликнуть второй раз по списку по item второй раз (учитывая что уже открыта эта тема новостей) приложение закрывается. Почему? Где мне искать проблему?

Вот MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    Fragment1 frag1;
    Fragment2 frag2;
    Fragment3 frag3;
    Fragment4 frag4;
    Fragment5 frag5;
    Fragment6 frag6;
    Fragment7 frag7;

    String[] web = { "News - Simferopol", "News - Science and Environment", "Politics", "International Football News", "African Football News", "News - Africa",
            "News - Europe" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frag1 = new Fragment1();
        frag2 = new Fragment2();
        frag3 = new Fragment3();
        frag4 = new Fragment4();
        frag5 = new Fragment5();
        frag6 = new Fragment6();
        frag7 = new Fragment7();

        ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, web);

        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, new Fragment1());
        trans.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutApp.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_feedback:
            Intent intentFeed = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FeedBack.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intentFeed);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_smile:
            Intent intentSmile = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Smile.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intentSmile);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag1);
            break;
        case 1:
            fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag2);
            break;
        case 2:
            fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag3);
            break;
        case 3:
            fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag4);
            break;
        case 4:
            fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag5);
            break;
        case 5:
            fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag6);
            break;
        case 6:
            fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag7);
        default:
            break;
        }
        fTrans.commit();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        style="@+styles/CustomListView"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: смотрите в logcat. Раз приложение вылетает - там должно быть какое-то исключение с стектрейсом.

Comment: Skipping entry 0x7f0a0001 in package table 0 because it is not complex!

Это все что там написано.

Comment: смотрите внимательнее. Может быть просто выключены предупреждения. Можно на другом девайсе/эмуляторе попробовать.

Comment: Запустила в другом эмуляторе. 
Вот что мне выдал: 
No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/ 

В манифесте доступ прописан к инету, а так же есть интент-фильтр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вписала одну строчку: fTrans.addToBackStack(null); после, все заработало!

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
    switch (position)
```